# Why the UIView did not rotate(iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift

I create a small UIView, and use animate method let it rotate forever:

```
    let v2=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30))
    v2.backgroundColor=UIColor.orange
    v2.transform=CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
    view.addSubview(v2)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat,.curveLinear], animations: {
        v2.transform=CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(Double.pi*2))
    }, completion:nil)
```

But I found that the UIView did not rotate at all,why?

Comment: Explained here: https://www.biteinteractive.com/taking-control-of-rotation-animations-in-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are effectively saying "rotate to its current rotation" -- so nothing happens.

Try it like this - rotate to 180-degrees (`.pi`)... the repeat will then rotate another 180-degrees, and another, and another, etc:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let v2=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30))
    v2.backgroundColor=UIColor.orange
    view.addSubview(v2)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat,.curveLinear], animations: {
        v2.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
    }, completion:nil)
    
}
```

---

**Edit** - a little more clarification...

If you want a continuous rotation, you can use the above code. Note, though, that if you want a **counter-clockwise** rotation, you'll need to use a negative rotation angle of *less-than* 180-degrees.

For example:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat,.curveLinear], animations: {
        v2.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi * 0.5)
    }, completion:nil)
```

That will rotate it 90-degrees counter-clockwise, and then again, and again, and again, etc.

On the other hand, if you only want it to rotate ***once*** (to any arbitrary angle, clockwise or counter-clockwise), you'll want to use `Core Animation` as explained in this excellent article by @matt:

[Taking Control of Rotation Animations in iOS](https://www.biteinteractive.com/taking-control-of-rotation-animations-in-ios/)

Comment: If I do not use "repeat" option, and I still want it to rotate to original position with animation, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Rotated but full cycle 360 degrees

```
v2.transform=CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(Double.pi*2))
```

Change it to this

```
v2.transform=CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(Double.pi*2/3))
```

To verify that rotate happens